# Difference between $POST and $_POST in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know what the difference is between $POST and $_POST in PHP.

```
<form method="post" action="practics.php">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="submit" name="check">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($POST['check']))
{
}
?>
```

Comment: One is a made variable and the other is a built in super global. Your example basically is a bug in the code.

Answer (score 6):

*"Difference between $POST and $_POST in PHP."*

So you want to know the difference between both.

It's simple, the first one will throw off an `Notice: Undefined variable: POST`, it being a superglobal, the underscore MUST be used.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

when having error reporting set to catch and display:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 3):

One is a mistake and the other isn't. `$_POST` is a superglobal whereas `$POST` appears to be somebody forgetting the underscore.

It could also be a standard variable but more than likely it's a mistake.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php